# MongoDB Replica Set setup is giving - SocketException: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to setup a `MongoDB replica set` and I'm getting the following error while starting the server.

`MongoDB` version is `4.0.2` and I'm trying to install on `Ubuntu 18.04`

```
2018-11-03T14:17:21.463+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-11-03T14:17:21.463+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-11-03T14:17:21.463+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-11-03T14:17:21.463+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2018-11-03T14:17:21.463+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-11-03T14:17:21.463+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-11-03T14:17:21.463+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1,dbtwo.example.net,dbthree.example.net", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { timeZoneInfo: "/usr/share/zoneinfo" }, replication: { replSetName: "rs0" }, security: { keyFile: "/opt/mongo/key1" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2018-11-03T14:17:21.477+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Cannot assign requested address
2018-11-03T14:17:21.477+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-11-03T14:17:21.477+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
```

How do i resolve it?

Comment: Check out if you have anything running on that port maybe and kill it? Or are you running on it on a AWS instance maybe and that you need to use admin and shutdown the server?

Comment: I'm running on Digitalocean, Will check if port is occupied.

Comment: Port was not used at all.

Comment: Is it able to resolve these hostnames: dbtwo.example.net,dbthree.example.net?  What does those hostnames resolve to?

Comment: Maybe restrart your mongodb instance .... Or check your bindIp values.... If not try this link:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: @Astro these are other mongodb instances running on different VMs

Comment: @JoeA I used DOs one click MongoDB itself to install it and allowed ufw

Comment: why are you binding ips of other mongodb instances running to this mongod process?

Comment: @Astro I'm trying to create a replica set configuration. The dbtwo and dbthree are the secondary servers. Should I not include them there?

Comment: no,  you can use their respective ips to bind in their own config

Comment: Didn't understand. 

The servers run with the `mongod.conf` file's `bindIp` set to `127.0.0.1` but when i include `dbtwo` and `dbthree` it fails.

Comment: you're trying to bind it with hostnames of other vm's which is not required and shouldn't be done.

Comment: Oh okay. Will remove them and bind only their respective IPs. Then using the `rs` command set bind others. Okay right?

Comment: I thought the `net.bindIp's` here meant all other hostname's of the replica set secondary instances.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-with-keyfile-access-control/#configuration-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the bind ip with the ips or hostnames of the same instance/vm where your mongodb is running.

For example:

- on vm1:  bindIp: 192.168.10.12
- on vm2:  bindIp: 192.168.10.13
- on vm3:  bindIp: 192.168.10.14

However, note that setting up bindIp to 127.0.0.1 will bind to only local loopback ip and will not be accesible from servers running on other vms'.

You need to bind them with appropriate internal ip or resolvable hostname.

Comment: Oh okay, So I'll set it up like

VM1: bindIp: dbone.example.net
VM2: bindIp: dbtwo.example.net
VM3: bindIp: dbthree.example.net

Correct right?

Comment: on vm1 bindIp: dbone.example.net , on vm2 bindIp=dtwo.example.net and so on

Comment: Cool, Thanks. Will test it out and ask again if i get a problem.